# How can I lock an SQL Server database for changes?

Tags: sql-server, locking

I want to make sure my database (SQL Server 2008) remains immutable, but still accessible for reads during some maintenance operations (backups, transitions to other DB servers etc),
how can I programmatically lock it for changes in C#?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can execute an `ALTER DATABASE <mydb> SET READ_ONLY` to put a database in read-only mode.

If you want the command to fail if it can't be executed immediately you specify it like this:

```
    ALTER DATABASE <mydb> 
    SET READ_ONLY
    WITH NO_WAIT
```

If you want to make it rollback all open connections you specify the command like this:

```
    ALTER DATABASE <mydb> 
    SET READ_ONLY
    WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
```

These options are well documented in [SQL Server Books online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522682.aspx)

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work some of the times, but half of the times I execute the query (in SQL Server Management Studio) the execution hangs and does not return...

Comment: You can specify `WITH NO_WAIT` so it fails immediately when it can not perform the command due to open transactions etc. Or you can specify `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` to make it rollback all open transactions.